License / patent consideration of ffmpeg in mobile app (react native ffmpeg kit)
So I am using the react native ffmpeg kit in my mobile app, it is a closed source, commercial app.
I am using the following functions/modules in the app:

Trim video
ffprobe to get frame count.
add overlay png to video
use minterpolate
use libx264

and I am using the default package (per the document page, it has https enable by default)
So I am wondering is this allowed in terms of software license and patent?
If not, what can I do in order to meet these license and patent requirements?
Thanks

You may want to try https://opensource.stackexchange.com/.
